# toggle todos checkbox trigger build function everytime

Tags: flutter, riverpod

for RiverPod official todos sample, system triggers build function whenever I toggle checkbox item, is it a correct behavior ? Won't it cause performance issue? thanks.

As I know, state management has one purpose to avoid rendering widgets so often. Please correct me if any.

Answer (score 0):

if you are watching your provider inside your build method then **yes** it rebuilds your entire build method. but if your want your the check box to only rebuild when necessary then its either (1) separates that into another class or (2) wraps that check box with `Consumer Widget`. something like:

```html
Consumer(
builder(_, ref, __){
final checkboxProvider = ref.watch(yourCheckboxProvider);

return CheckBox();

}
)
```